# Scala for-yield control flow

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I was wondering the control flow in a scala in  a for-yield block. I see that all elements first go through the 'for' part followed by 'yield' part. Why is that? Should it not be for-yield for element1, for-yield for element2...

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val t = for {
  i <- list
  log = println("processing " + i)
} yield {
  println("In yield for " + i)
  i
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

processing 1   //All of them first go through the for block
processing 2
processing 3
processing 4
processing 5
processing 6
In yield for 1    // yield comes after all
In yield for 2
In yield for 3
In yield for 4
In yield for 5
In yield for 6
t: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Comment: It depends on the type of your first thing in the `for`. 
Try `Stream` instead of `List`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this comment? Tried stream and it just processes first element.  Why list behaves this particular way is what I am wondering.

Comment: The "list behaves this paticular way", bcause that's how it is implemented.
`Stream` is implemented in a diffrent way. To adding `.toList` to the end of the snipped that "just processes first element"

Comment: may be I didn't phrase my question clearly. Talking about list, does it mean that `for` block for all the elements is processed first, stored in heap, then `yield` kicks in and start creating response from processed `for` block which is now in memory? That is what I meant by flow.

Comment: Can you imagine another way it could work?

Comment: don't want to imagine but looking for facts. Can you  imaging a better answer than what you gave?

Comment: Nope, I can't. I think, my answer was the best you could possibly get to this question. Now think. If you don't want to imagine, then just think. You can't hope to get all possible "facts" of the Universe from internet. At some points, you are going to start replacing "facts" with deductions, conclusions and even assumptions.

Comment: Cool thanks for your earlier answers. They helped me.

Comment: @Dima: I would have naively expected like Richeek that the `log` evaluation to happen right before the respective iteration needs it - but apparently, that's not what the `for` desugars into. You might want to put up an answer that clearly shows the intermediate list.

Comment: Not sure why negative vote! People please be kind enough to tell what is wrong with the question and not just arbitrarily vote down something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code

```
val t = for {
  i <- list
  log = println("processing " + i)
} yield {
  println("In yield for " + i)
  i
}
```

roughly desugars into

```
val t = list.map { i =>
    val log = println("processing " + i)
    (i, log)
}.map { x =>
    x match {
        case (i, log) =>
            println("In yield for " + i)
    }
}
```

From here you can see why you get all of the "processing ..." messages first.